# How to set up Azure Active directory to return tenant ID and other attributes to Keycloak

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

I have a web app which used Keycloak as Identity Management service.
In Keycloak i have set up several social Identity providers; Google and Microsoft.
Because my web app is multi-tenant, i want to receive the organisation domain or identifier from the social Identity provider. Google returns the "hd" attribute, which i can map to whatever user attribute i want. But Microsoft Azure Active Directory does not seem to return an attribute i can use. The keycloak log shows the following json response:

```
21:58:32,624 DEBUG [org.keycloak.social.user_profile_dump] (default task-237) User Profile JSON Data for provider microsoft: {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity","displayName":"Robin Test","surname":"Test","givenName":"Robin","id":"00ed96cbb71f74aa","userPrincipalName":"robin@test.io","businessPhones":[],"jobTitle":null,"mail":null,"mobilePhone":null,"officeLocation":null,"preferredLanguage":null}
```

The azure documentation states there is a Tenant ID (tid attribute) but it unclear what to configure in Azure to get that to be sent to Keycloak. The companyName attribute would also suffice.

I spent the better part of a day trying to solve this, but no further. Any help appreciated. In Google this was 10 minutes to set up :(

Comment: The token should contain it, the profile endpoint won't have it I think.

Comment: I was (perhaps mistakenly) under the impressiont that DEBUG [org.keycloak.social.user_profile_dump] logs the JWT token from Azure? 

If so, what do i need to do in Azure to add the tenant ID.

If not, how should i tell Keycloak to request the token?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an Mapper to the Identiy-Provider. I used "Attribute Importer" as Type and tid as Claim. If the User is created, the attribute is set. And then you can use it in the token.

Comment: Keycloak mapping is not the problem; that works fine. The issue is how to receive the attributes from Azure AD in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Took another two days to figure out, but i managed to receive the tenant-id by setting up keycloak and Azure as follows:

1. In Azure create an Azure portal account for your own organisation,
   lets call this MyTenant In MyTenant, define an Enterprise
   application of type 'Non Gallery' This will automatically add an
   'app registration' with the same name. Lets call this MyApp. MyApp
   will only show up if you select All applications in the app
   registrations screen. N.B. The Enterprise application is an
   administrative reference to the app registration that allows the app
   registration to be shared with other Azure tenants
2. Select the app registration for MyApp it and fill in the Branding
   information. It is important to add your domain name, so you will
   need to verify that in Azure before starting. Change
   Authentication->Supported account type to 'Multi-Tenant' and add a
   Platform of type Single Page App. Define the redirect URI's to
   Keycloak and your app.
3. Under 'Expose an API' set the Application ID
   URI to a globally unique value, something like [https://MyApp.com]
   and add a scope user_impersonation Under API permissions, add at
   least: Microsoft Graph User.Read and My APIs -> [MyApp] ->
   user_impersonation
4. Create a link that you can send to a 'Global administrator' of the
   organisation you want to access keycloak, we'll call this
   organisation OtherTenant. Here is an example:

   ```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/[OtherTenant id or domain]/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=[Application ID of the app registration in MyTenant]&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/openid+https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All+[Application ID URI from MyTenant]/user_impersonation&state=[any value you want]&redirect_uri=[any url, e.g. http://localhost]
   ```
5. Once the administrator of OtherTenant clicks on this link they will
   be asked to allow access on behalf of their organisation. When they
   accept, all users can login with Microsoft.
6. Create a SAML Identity Provider in Keycloak the uses the urls:
   Single Sign-On Service URL:
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/saml2 Single Logout Service
   URL:
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0
7. The redirect URI in the keycloak Identity provider needs to be
   copied to Azure: Go to MyTenant Enterprise Applications and select
   MyApp, select 'Single sign on' and add the redirect URI in the Reply
   URL field under 'Basic SAML Configuration'
8. Add Identity Provider Mappings for the Attribute you want to map to Keycloak. The attribute i wanted was called http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid and is the tenant ID of OtherTenant